# How calculate clusters coherence/quality?

Tags: machine-learning, data-science, cluster-analysis, k-means, cosine-similarity

I did embeddings with fasttext and I have clusters thanks to KMeans.

I would like to calculate similarities inside each cluster to check if the sentences inside are well clustered. I want to keep sentences with good similarities in each clusters. If the similarity is not good, I want to exit sentence that not belong to a cluster, and next group similar sentences not belonging to clusters.

How can I do it in a good manner ? I thought using cosine similarity but don't know how to compare all sentences inside a cluster

Answer (score 3):

Maybe something like this...

```
# clustering words into similar groups:

import numpy as np
from sklearn.cluster import AffinityPropagation
import distance
    
words = 'XYZ,LDPELDKSL,DFKLKSLFD,ABC,DLFKFKDLD,XYZ,LDPELDKSL,DFKLKSLFD,ABC,DLFKFKDLD,XYZ,LDPELDKSL,XYZ,LDPELDKSL,DFKLKSLFD,ABC,DLFKFKDLD,XYZ,LDPELDKSL,DFKLKSLFD,ABC,DLFKFKDLD,XYZ,LDPELDKSL'.split(',') #Replace this line
words = np.asarray(words) #So that indexing with a list will work
lev_similarity = -1*np.array([[distance.levenshtein(w1,w2) for w1 in words] for w2 in words])

affprop = AffinityPropagation(affinity="precomputed", damping=0.5)
affprop.fit(lev_similarity)
for cluster_id in np.unique(affprop.labels_):
    exemplar = words[affprop.cluster_centers_indices_[cluster_id]]
    cluster = np.unique(words[np.nonzero(affprop.labels_==cluster_id)])
    cluster_str = ", ".join(cluster)
    print(" - *%s:* %s" % (exemplar, cluster_str))
```

Result:

```
- *LDPELDKSL:* LDPELDKSL
 - *DFKLKSLFD:* DFKLKSLFD
 - *XYZ:* ABC, XYZ
 - *DLFKFKDLD:* DLFKFKDLD
```

See these links for additional guidance on how to cluster text.

https://towardsdatascience.com/applying-machine-learning-to-classify-an-unsupervised-text-document-e7bb6265f52

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/text/plot_document_clustering.html

https://pythonprogramminglanguage.com/kmeans-text-clustering/

http://brandonrose.org/clustering

Here are a couple examples using Cosine Similarity.

```
d1 = "plot: two teen couples go to a church party, drink and then drive."
d2 = "films adapted from comic books have had plenty of success , whether they're about superheroes ( batman , superman , spawn ) , or geared toward kids ( casper ) or the arthouse crowd ( ghost world ) , but there's never really been a comic book like from hell before . "
d3 = "every now and then a movie comes along from a suspect studio , with every indication that it will be a stinker , and to everybody's surprise ( perhaps even the studio ) the film becomes a critical darling . "
d4 = "damn that y2k bug . "
documents = [d1, d2, d3, d4]
 
 
import nltk, string, numpy
nltk.download('punkt') # first-time use only
stemmer = nltk.stem.porter.PorterStemmer()

def StemTokens(tokens):
     return [stemmer.stem(token) for token in tokens]
remove_punct_dict = dict((ord(punct), None) for punct in string.punctuation)
def StemNormalize(text):
     return StemTokens(nltk.word_tokenize(text.lower().translate(remove_punct_dict)))
 
nltk.download('wordnet') # first-time use only
lemmer = nltk.stem.WordNetLemmatizer()
def LemTokens(tokens):
     return [lemmer.lemmatize(token) for token in tokens]
remove_punct_dict = dict((ord(punct), None) for punct in string.punctuation)
def LemNormalize(text):
     return LemTokens(nltk.word_tokenize(text.lower().translate(remove_punct_dict)))


from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
LemVectorizer = CountVectorizer(tokenizer=LemNormalize, stop_words='english')
LemVectorizer.fit_transform(documents)
 
 
print(LemVectorizer.vocabulary_)


tf_matrix = LemVectorizer.transform(documents).toarray()
print(tf_matrix)


tf_matrix.shape


from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer
tfidfTran = TfidfTransformer(norm="l2")
tfidfTran.fit(tf_matrix)
print(tfidfTran.idf_)


import math
def idf(n,df):
    result = math.log((n+1.0)/(df+1.0)) + 1
    return result
print("The idf for terms that appear in one document: " + str(idf(4,1)))
print("The idf for terms that appear in two documents: " + str(idf(4,2)))


tfidf_matrix = tfidfTran.transform(tf_matrix)
print(tfidf_matrix.toarray())


cos_similarity_matrix = (tfidf_matrix * tfidf_matrix.T).toarray()
print(cos_similarity_matrix)


from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
TfidfVec = TfidfVectorizer(tokenizer=LemNormalize, stop_words='english')
def cos_similarity(textlist):
    tfidf = TfidfVec.fit_transform(textlist)
    return (tfidf * tfidf.T).toarray()
cos_similarity(documents)
```

https://sites.temple.edu/tudsc/2017/03/30/measuring-similarity-between-texts-in-python/

```
# Define the documents
doc_trump = "Mr. Trump became president after winning the political election. Though he lost the support of some republican friends, Trump is friends with President Putin"
doc_election = "President Trump says Putin had no political interference is the election outcome. He says it was a witchhunt by political parties. He claimed President Putin is a friend who had nothing to do with the election"
doc_putin = "Post elections, Vladimir Putin became President of Russia. President Putin had served as the Prime Minister earlier in his political career"
documents = [doc_trump, doc_election, doc_putin]


# Scikit Learn
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
import pandas as pd

# Create the Document Term Matrix
count_vectorizer = CountVectorizer(stop_words='english')
count_vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
sparse_matrix = count_vectorizer.fit_transform(documents)

# OPTIONAL: Convert Sparse Matrix to Pandas Dataframe if you want to see the word frequencies.
doc_term_matrix = sparse_matrix.todense()
df = pd.DataFrame(doc_term_matrix, 
                  columns=count_vectorizer.get_feature_names(), 
                  index=['doc_trump', 'doc_election', 'doc_putin'])
df

# Compute Cosine Similarity
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
print(cosine_similarity(df, df))
```

https://www.machinelearningplus.com/nlp/cosine-similarity/

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer it works well ! Do you know if I can do the same with cosine similarity instead of lev distance ?

Comment: I just added some cosine similarity examples to my original post.

Comment: Thanks, once I have the similarities will it work the same way with affinity propagation algorithm ?

Comment: All clustering algos are at least slightly different, and sometimes completely different! Also, sometimes the starting point is random, so running the process multiple times can produce slightly different results. I guess you can try it, and see what the outcome is.